# Changes sent through PutAsync() won't register

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm trying to make changes to existing objects in my database through a UWP app, and I have so far been able to create objects, delete them, and read/display them. But I can't for the life of me get updating to work.

I've looked around, and I've seen people use this method, but I can't seem to get it to work:

```
var existingBook = new Book
{
    Title = TitleBox.Text,
    Author = AuthorBox.Text,
    Isbn = IsbnBox.Text,
    Description = DescBox.Text,
    Id= int.Parse(IdBox.Text)
};

using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existingBook);
    var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var result = await client.PutAsync(App.BaseUri, httpContent);
    string contentRecieved = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

I import the existing values of a book to different text boxes so that they can be edited, and then when I press the button that runs the code above, it tries to send those changes, but none of the edits made seem to go through.

I've also tried the example of Updating from [this page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/crud-operations-in-uwa-using-web-api/), which would look like so:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
{
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(existingBook);
    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        var data = new FormUrlEncodedContent(
        new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            ["value"] = content,
            ["id"] = App.Books.Id.ToString()
        }
        );
        await client.PutAsync(App.BaseUri, data);
    });
    task.Wait();
}
```

This doesn't seem to make the edits stick either... I get no errors or crashes from either of the two methods, but they just don't seem to work.

I would really appreciate some help with this...

Comment: What database are you using that requires a REST API to access it?

Comment: We have our own "local" database that we use. Not sure what's behind it.

Comment: Why do you think the problem is with your code?  If your company has written their own API, maybe it's that that is not working and you should check those logs,

Comment: They haven't made their own API (as far as I know), we are using Entity Framework and ASP.Net Web API

Comment: That sounds to me like they've created their own API.  EF/ASP doesn't have a 'database API' you have to write your own.  Can you run the API project locally and post your request to it?  Maybe you could use Fiddler or Postmaster to create the POST ?